# Regex to handle unicode strings in evil mode

Tags: evil, regular-expressions

I'm using evil mode on Emacs2 27.1 on OSX. My goal is to search and replace some text containing unicode strings using either of emacs' replace-regex or vim's search/replace functionality.

To begin with, let me showcase the example in vim **without** the use of unicode characters:

My text file has plenty of markers (let's say the unicode char `।` i.e U2404) and I need to wrap the marker along with its preceding word into `\mbox{}`

E.g input text

```
This is a string।
This is another (string) ।
One more example string here    ।
```

This regex does the job for me in vim: `%s/\((\?\w*)\?\)\s*।/\\mbox{\1 ।}/g`

Output

```
This is a \mbox{string ।}
This is another \mbox{(string) ।}
One more example string \mbox{here ।}
```

Now, onto solving the real problem with unicode chars. Sample text:

```
This is a नमस्ते।
This is another (नमस्ते) ।
One more example string नमस्ते    ।
```

The above vim regex does not work because `\w` does not match unicode chars. However, I can use `\S`, which denotes any non-space character, in the regex to apply the search/replace with pattern `%s/\((\?\S*)\?\)\s*।/\\mbox{\1 ।}/gc`

This regex does **not** work in emacs' evilmode. Is there such a thing as `\S` in emacs' regex repertoire? I glanced through emacs' regex syntax and couldn't find anything.

What's the regex to use to obtain the same results as with the vim command `%s/\((\?\S*)\?\)\s*।/\\mbox{\1 ।}/gc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use evil mode, so I've no idea if its regexes are different from ordinary Emacs regexes or not.

But if you use `M-x re-builder`, you'll see that `"\\((?\\w*)?\\) *।"` is a perfectly fine regex that matches all of your examples, with the group matching exactly what you want.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!